# Nuxt Vuex Helper not sending Client Cookies to API

Tags: cookies, nuxt.js, vuex, server-side-rendering, refresh-token

Okay, I have the bad feeling that I'm missing a key concept in what I'm doing. Hope someone can help me out with a hint.

I'm using Nuxt and Vuex Store Modules. Every fetch a Module Action does is wrapped in a helper Function (`saveFetch`) that I imported to decrease repetitive code, like this:

```js
export const actions = {
    async sampleAction(context, data){
        ...
        await saveFetch(context, 'POST', '/pages', data)
        ...
    }
}
```

The helper simple checks if the users `accessToken` is still valid, refreshes it if not and then sends the request:

```js
export const saveFetch = async (context, method = 'POST', path, data) => {

    const accessTokenExpiry = context.rootGetters['auth/getAccessTokenExpiry']
    let accessToken = context.rootGetters['auth/getAccessToken']

    // If the client provides an accessToken and the accessToken is expired,
    // refresh the token before making the "real" fetch.
    if (accessToken && accessTokenExpiry < new Date() && path !== '/auth/refresh-token') {
        if (process.client) {
            // Works fine
            await window.$nuxt.$store.dispatch('auth/refreshToken')
        } else {
            // This is where the trouble starts
            await context.dispatch('auth/refreshToken', null, { root: true })
        }
        accessToken = rootGetters['auth/getAccessToken']
    }

    return fetch(path, {
        method,
        headers: { ... },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }
}
```

If the `accessToken` is expired the helper function dispatches a Vuex Action to refresh it. This works well on the client side, but not if that process happens on the server side.

The Problem that's coming up on the server side is, that the user has to provide a `refreshToken` to get a refreshed `accessToken` from the API. This `refreshToken` is stored as a HttpOnly Cookie in the Client. When logging the Nuxt request details on the API side of things I noticed, that Nuxt is not sending that cookie.

My current workaround looks like this:

```js
export const actions = {
    async refreshToken(context){
        ...
        let refreshToken
        if (process?.server && this?.app?.context?.req?.headers?.cookie) {
            const parsedCookies = cookie.parse(
                this.app.context.req.headers.cookie
            )
            refreshToken = parsedCookies?.refreshToken
        }
        const response = await saveFetch(context, 'POST', '/auth/refresh-token', {
            refreshToken,
        })
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If on server side, access the `req` object, get the cookies from it and send the `refreshToken` Cookie Content in the requests body.

This looks clearly bad to me and I would love to get some feedback on how to do this better. Did I maybe miss some key concepts that would help me not get into this problem in the first place?

Comment: Hey, I’ve dealt with something similar before. I’m wondering, in your use case, if it’s necessary for the saveFetch method to run on the node side at all? Your client side method works fine as it is, where are you finding it necessary to issue a fetch to your api from the node instance?

Comment: Haha glad I'm not the only one @NickDawes  I need to call this method on the server side if a users access token expired and he coincidentally refreshes the page after expiry and before triggering any action in the client which would fetch a new access token.

Comment: Ah maybe to clarify this a little bit more... the api I'm sending my requests to for authenticating is another node server than the one that's running my nuxt instance.

Comment: How was your solution when you had the same case @NickDawes?

Comment: With the correct axios configuration, the browser will attach the cookies to all requests by default. All I needed to do was have the client side app check the store for a user, if none were present (eg. due to a hard refresh) my client side method would send a request to my Laravel app to grab the currently authenticated user. If I were logged in, the request would include he cookies and Laravel would send the authenticated user back in it's response. If I were not logged in, no user was returned and I handled it client-side. SO comment character limit- hope this is helpful to you!